# Spring.Net. ContextRegistry.GetContext() exception, cannot configure Common.Logging

Tags: c#, spring, spring.net

I cannot get the IApplication context for my console app

I get an exception with this detail:
`The type initializer for 'Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry' threw an exception.`

With inner exception:
`Could not configure Common.Logging from configuration section 'common/logging`

There's clearly something basic I've not hooked up, but I'm not sure what.

```
using Spring.Context;
using Spring.Context.Support;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
       }
   }
}
```

And my app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
      <description>An  example that demonstrates simple IoC features.                  </description>
    </objects>
  </spring>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Code is moviefinder from http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/quickstarts.html

Comment: Have you tried out the actual code from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/tree/master/examples/Spring/Spring.IoCQuickStart.MovieFinder as a start? First thing I noticed: you didn't specify any objects inside the <objects>...</objects>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring.Net uses Common Logging as facility for logging, you have to add the logging configuration to your `app.config` and the proper library to the referenced assemblies.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
        <arg key="level" value="DEBUG" />
        <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
        <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
        <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
</configuration>
```

http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/docs/1.2.0/reference/html/logging.html#logging-declarative-config

Answer (score 2):

> The type initializer for 'Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry'
>   threw an exception

This is valueable information and Spring.net is really good at providing additional information. Whenever Spring.net throws something, be sure to read the `InnerException`.

> WHen I edit my config I get the messages: Could not find schema
>   information for the attribute #. for # = 'uri', 'context', 'resource'
>   and 'spring'

This is normal if you didn't install the schemas. You can [download the schemas](http://www.springframework.net/xsd/) at their site and find [additional information in their docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/vsnet.html). Please note that this is optional and spring runs without those schemas.

Comment: Yes, sorry, of course check the inner exception. I've posted that now. Yes, as you say, the schemas are irrelevant.

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the whole app.config? I built a very similar example and it works fine: https://gist.github.com/tobi-tobsen/eac1ba1ee3a0f9b890c4

Comment: I missed the bit that says it targets .Net 4.5